# Finding the filled side of an SVG path

Tags: svg, postscript

I am creating an animation the camera moves along the path from `M` to `z` (closed path). As the camera moves, I need to know which side is inside the closed path.

Since the inside of a path is formed by clockwise move (in the default `fill-rule` of `nonzero`), I assumed the inside is always on the right side of the path.

However, I encountered cases where the filled area is on the left side of the path.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.986 26.986"><path d="M.614 2.145V24.84C.614 26.028 1.575 26.986 2.759 26.986H24.226C25.41 26.986 26.372 26.027 26.372 24.84V2.145C26.372 .963 25.409 0 24.225 0H2.759C1.575 0 .614 .963 .614 2.145zM8.778 20.82C8.778 22.353 7.534 23.599 6.001 23.599C4.466 23.599 3.224 22.353 3.224 20.82C3.224 19.289 4.466 18.043 6.001 18.043C7.534 18.043 8.778 19.289 8.778 20.82zM23.696 5.596C23.696 7.131 22.45 8.375 20.917 8.375C19.386 8.375 18.142 7.131 18.142 5.596C18.142 4.063 19.386 2.819 20.917 2.819C22.45 2.818 23.696 4.062 23.696 5.596z"/>
<circle cx="0.614" cy="2.145" r="2" fill="red"/>
<path d="M.614 2.145V24.84" stroke="blue"  />
</svg>
```

I know we can check if a typical point is inside the closed path by polygon methods.

I wonder if there is a simpler method for finding the inside of a closed path when moving from `M` to `z`?

***I just need to know when moving from `M` to `z`, the inside of the closed path is on the right or left side of the camera.***

Comment: If you imaging a person moving along the path, the inside is always on the right side of the person. This assumes the person is always looking in the direction of the path at that specific point. The camera might be rotated and look to one side of the person. Sharp corners are an exception as they don't have a direction. But it applies immediately before and after the corner.

Comment: @Codo I believe it should be the case, but in the above SVG, I added the starting point (red circle) and the first line (blue stroke). As you can see the filled area is on the left side of the blue line if starting from the red circle. Where do I do the mistake?

Comment: Are you working in a DOM environment? Then you could test if a point is inside with the [SVGGeometryElement.isPointIinFill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill) interface.

Comment: @ccprog Since I do not have a point of interest, I should choose an arbitrary point. The choice can cause a mistake. You can choose a point that is on the correct side but far enough to be outside the filled area.

Comment: True, But that is as far as you get. Even the `fill-rule` only identifies if a certain point of interest is on the inside or outside. Btw, that works like this: choose a point, draw a line **to infinity** and count the number of times you cross the path. Right and left only affect whether you count up or down, but both can contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assumption

> ...the inside of a path is formed by clockwise move...

is only true if the path is non-overlapping and does not define a hole. If your path never crosses itself and has no holes, the inside will always be to your right *assuming that you are following the path in a clockwise move*. However, in your example the movement from the red dot through the blue line is counterclockwise.

A general solution to this problem would be long and laborious. However, depending on the design of your script, it might be much simpler. If you are always drawing your figure clockwise (as in your example), the inside is to your rigth when you follow the same order of points, and to your left if you are reversing the order of your points. Notice that in your example you are reversing the order of points - the path is closed from the last point (z) to the first (M).

If not, this procedure should work:

- Start with the point where the camera is and the vector showing where it points.
- Rotate this vector by any angle higher than 0 and lower than π (that would be *to the left*).
- Follow the vector from the point of the camera and find how many times it intersects with your path (current segment excluded). If this number is even, the inside is to the right of the camera. If the number is odd, it is to the left.

This is feasible, but by no means trivial. For the third step, you might use the bounding box of your path as "infinity". To exclude the *current segment*, your procedure to find the intersection of two segments should return `false` if one of the extremes of one segment belongs to the other segment. It should also return `false` if both segments are parallel. You would also need to decide the behavior you want in special points, such as vertices.